# how to make my program ask the questions one after the other

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
    cmdangry.Click, cmdconfused.Click, cmdsad.Click, cmdhappy.Click, cmdtired.Click, cmdhurt.Click, cmdexcited.Click, cmdsurprised.Click



        Dim answer As Integer = 0
        Dim question As Integer

        Select Case DirectCast(sender, Button).Name
                Case cmdconfused.Name
                    answer += 1
                Case cmdangry.Name
                    answer += 2
                Case cmdsad.Name
                    answer += 3

                Case cmdhappy.Name
                    answer += 4

                Case cmdtired.Name
                    answer += 5

                Case cmdhurt.Name
                    answer += 6

                Case cmdexcited.Name
                    answer += 7

                Case cmdsurprised.Name
                    answer += 8

            End Select
```

This is my code and I am going to have my program ask a question like "if I feel sad what face would I make" then the user would press the corresponding button (cmdsad) and then a textbox will light up green for a few seconds and if it is wrong it will light up red. I can't seem to figure out how to make my program ask the questions one after the other. I know how to set up the if-else statements. Note the questions will be asked using a voice recording

Comment: Add the questions to a collection of some sort - probably a `Queue(Of T)` - and then get the next question from the collection each time the `Button` is clicked.

Comment: @jmlcilhinney  how would i do that?

Comment: You posted your comment 5 minutes after mine, which means that you gave it no thought or did any research for yourself. Make an effort first, ask when you encounter an issue.

Comment: @jmlcilhinney thats the thing i genuinely dont know how to do that. I apologise if it seems like i have not made an effort but i genuinely have spent multiple hours on this

Comment: Did you know that you should use a collection before? Now you do, so you have something specific to research that you didn't before. Have you read the documentation for the `Queue(Of T)` class? Have you searched the web for information on how to add and remove items in a `Queue(Of T)`? Multiple hours of spinning your wheels is of no consequence. When someone gives you something specific to look into, look into it. You may still need further help to get the whole way but you can still try to get part of the way yourself.

Comment: Why are you `+=`  `answer`? Since `answer` is declared in the event procedure, its value is lost at `End Sub`. The next time any of the buttons are clicked, it start at zero again.

Comment: How about `"cmdconfused"` instead of `cmdconfused.Name`